# HTTP Status 500 - Provider org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl not found

Tags: java, json, tomcat, netbeans

I am using `netbeans-8, jdk 7,tomcat 8.05.` I created a webapp in `netbeans` and added `javax.json` api to my project, the code shows no errors, but when i run my servlet the below error occurs.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Provider org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl not found

type Exception report

message Provider org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl not found

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.json.JsonException: Provider org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl not found
    javax.json.spi.JsonProvider.provider(JsonProvider.java:97)
    javax.json.Json.createObjectBuilder(Json.java:266)
    NewServlet.doGet(NewServlet.java:24)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1284)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1132)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    javax.json.spi.JsonProvider.provider(JsonProvider.java:94)
    javax.json.Json.createObjectBuilder(Json.java:266)
    NewServlet.doGet(NewServlet.java:24)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.3 logs.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.3
```

Answer (score 25):

The javax.json api (provided in the JSON Processing API jar) is good only for compiling the application.

If you want to run the application, you have to download the [JSON Processing RI jar](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/glassfish/javax.json/1.0.4/javax.json-1.0.4.jar), as explained here: https://jsonp.java.net/download.html

The JSON Processing RI jar contains the org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl class you are missing.

Answer (score 23):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18282982/1206998) you could replace javax.json dependency by its org.glassfish implementation.

[Maven repo](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/javax.json), gives:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: After adding this to dependencies list, no use((

Answer (score 6):

I managed to make it work in my webapp in NetBeans by manually installing the JSON Processing RI jar.

The complete procedure is:

- Download the jar: [JSON Processing RI jar](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/glassfish/javax.json/1.0.4/javax.json-1.0.4.jar)
- Right-click on Project --> Dependencies and add new dependency providing dummy Group ID, Artifact ID and Version number.
- Right-click on the newly created dependency and select "Manually install artifact", provide the downloaded jar
- Rebuild project, now it should work